# Nuxt.js router-module not working with dynamic parameter

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

I am working on Nuxtjs application and I'm using [router-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module).
Static route is working however dynamic routing is not working. For example when I access url /users/123, it showing Not Found. here is my router file:

```
 {
      path: '/user/:id',
      name: 'user',
      component: user
  }
```

Comment: closing this question since it happen due to  issue on my end

Comment: ok just do it. ..